# Using tidyr to select columns in a certain order given by a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select certain columns in a `data.frame` with the `select` function from `library(dplyr)`. The columns are given in a vector and I can use `one_of()` to do so:

```
library(dplyr)

ddf <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 2:1, C = LETTERS[1:2])
sel <- c("A", "C")

ddf %>% select(one_of(sel))
#   A C
# 1 1 A
# 2 2 B
```

I also can use also the form `-one_of(.)` to select everything but the given columns:

```
ddf %>% select(-one_of(sel))
#   B
# 1 2
# 2 1
```

But if I try to combine both, I get an unexpected result:

```
ddf %>% select(-one_of(sel), one_of(sel)) # works as expected
#   B A C
# 1 2 1 A
# 2 1 2 B

ddf %>% select(one_of(sel), -one_of(sel)) ## does not work as expected
# data frame with 0 columns and 2 rows
```

Is this behaviour intentional? And how can I bring my columns into a certain order with `select` without negating `sel` that is `sel <- "B"`would not be an option ;)

Comment: What is that "*certain order*" that you desire your columns to bring to? You can generate any order using lets say `ddf %>% select(2, 3, 1)`. Also, any reason you can't just do these stuff with base R?

Comment: I want to select columns in the order they appear in `sel` first and then all the other columns which do not appear in `sel`

Comment: You can also do `ddf %>% select(one_of(sel), everything())`

Comment: Ah interesting, works unexpectedly correct. Would you post that as an answer then I could accept the answer.

Comment: To your other points, of course there are plenty of other ways to do so, but I want to use `select` because I like to stay in the same semantics and I use `tidyr` and `dplyr` afterwards a lot, so I find the code more readable if I stick to same verbs. I want to avoid to hardcode the order in the `select` statement as I have already defined `sel` somewhere else in my code and I want to reuse it to avoid duplication.

Comment: Ok then, you can post it then. I don't feel like posting this solution as it annoys me and I would never use it in real life. I would go with `ddf[c(sel, setdiff(names(ddf), sel))]` or such

Comment: But finally I am still interested, why `select(one_of(sel), -one_of(sel))` does not work while `select(-one_of(sel), one_of(sel))` works. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112170/discussion-between-thothal-and-david-arenburg).

Comment: Regarding your last comment, the first one doesn't work because you are telling `select` :"*select column 1 and 3, then unselect columns 1 and 3*", hence you are practically telling it to select nothing. In the second case its: "*don't select 1 and 3, then select 1 and 3*" hence you are telling it to keep columns 1 and 3. Though I'm not sure where column 2 comes from in the result. Either way, those functions are all R wrappers so you can easily recreate them using the [source](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-utils.R#L110).

Comment: Ah this makes sense, so even the first verb then makes sense, becasue you tell `select` to *select everything but columns 1 and 3 (=column 2) and then select columns 1 and 3*. Make sense now to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by @[David Arenburg] the solution is to use:

```
ddf %>% select(one_of(sel), everything())
```